# why the clion rust tell serde::Serialize as unused import

Tags: rust, clion

Recently I was open the CLion Rust plugin unused import sniff `Settings > Editor > Inspections > Rust > Lints > Unused Import`, sometimes the rust show the wrong way, for example:

```
use rust_wheel::common::util::convert_to_tree::IntoTree;
use serde::Serialize;
use crate::model::diesel::fortune::fortune_models::FortuneContent;
use crate::model::response::contents::fortune_contents_response::FortuneContentResponse;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Default)]
pub struct EditContentResponse {
    pub own: Vec<FortuneContent>,
    pub available: Vec<FortuneContent>
}
```

the CLion Rust plugin shows the `use serde::Serialize;` was unused import. But actually this import was used by the code. is it possible to make the plugin recognized this import the correct way? The rustc did not tell the `use serde::Serialize;` was unused. is is possible to fix it? This feature was very helpful.

Comment: Does rustc also warns about an unused import? If not, this is probably a bug of CLion. Specifically, it may mean it does not expand proc macros.

Comment: the rustc did not warns about as unused improt. @ChayimFriedman

Comment: Then you can try to report a bug to the CLion developers, or wait until somebody more knowledgeable than me about its internal will respond here.

Comment: This issue seems happen for years. @ChayimFriedman https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues/8630